# Clear background color of delete button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have background image for every cell of table view, when i swipe delete button appears, the problem is that a square of white color(default cell color) appears behind the delete button, i want to get rid of that white square, so how to clear background color of delete button?

Comment: try setting background color of cells to `[UIColor clearColor];`

Answer (score 0):

If u have create button dynamically then use react round type button. if u have same problem then u choose custom type button. If u have drag and drop then unchecked opaque quality of button in view section.